# Java String DateTime to toEpochMilli - Different Regions

Tags: java, timezone, epoch, region, datetime-conversion

I am developing a string conversion method for toEpochMilli(). But I am getting different results when I publish the code on a different time zone region server. How to solve ?

```
    //input = "2019-12-26T00:00:00"

    private static Long converter(String stringDate) {
        try {
            LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(stringDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"));
            ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo");
            return dateTime.atZone(zoneId).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
        } catch (DateTimeParseException dte) {
            throw new DateException("Invalid input format", dte);
        }
    }
```

The Sao Paulo output is converted to LocalDateTime the same result as the input is obtained, but the North Virginia output is converted to LocalDateTime a different result is obtained from the input.

```
public static String backConverter(Long epochMilli) {
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochMilli), ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
    return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").format(localDateTime);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you're converting this `Long` back into a `LocalDateTime`?  Which time zone are you using for that?

Comment: can you show the output you are getting ? for me your code works fine

Comment: when run in sao paulo = "2019-12-26T00:00:00"

Comment: Is your input same during both timezones ? @phdias I believe your input is changing at different time zones

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I called `converter()` and then `backConverter()` on a JVM in `America/New_York` time zone (where I believe Virginia belongs). I got `2019-12-26T00:00:00`. I also tried modifying both of your methods to use that time zone. Still the same result. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please.

Comment: same code run in north virginia = "2019-12-25T23:00:00"

Comment: this change works now. - ZoneId.systemDefault();

Answer (score 1):

This solution works in differents places with same outputs.

```
//input = "2019-12-26T00:00:00"

private static Long converter(String stringDate) {
    try {
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(stringDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"));
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();
        return dateTime.atZone(zoneId).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    } catch (DateTimeParseException dte) {
        throw new DateException("Invalid input format", dte);
    }
}

public static String backConverter(Long epochMilli) {
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochMilli), ZoneId.systemDefault());
    return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").format(localDateTime);
}
```